# Finding the WiFi network name (SSID) in OS X via shell script

Tags: macos, wireless-networking, shell-script

How can I find the WiFi network name I'm connected to on Snow Leopard via shell script?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
network_SSID="$(/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport -I | sed -e "s/^  *SSID: //p" -e d)"
```

Answer (score 4):

```
#!/bin/bash
SSID=$(/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport -I | awk -F': ' '/ SSID/ {print $2}')
echo $SSID
```